# Print layout of C++ object with g++ compiler

Tags: c++, g++, memory-layout

Is there a way to print the layout of a C++ object using the g++ compiler or any other means. 
A simplified example (assuming int takes 4 bytes)

```
class A{
  int a;
};

class B:public A{
  int b;
}
```

so the output would be

```
A-
0      4
+  a   +

B-
0      4      8
+ A.a  +  b   +
```

It would be useful to understand the layout of objects (in my case virtual machine code).

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Zaheer

Answer (score 12):

Looking at the man pages, `-fdump-class-hierarchy` maybe?

Note that since GCC 8, the `-fdump-class-hierarchy` option has been replaced with `-fdump-lang-class`.

Comment: This is an option of g++ (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/Developer-Options.html), although I am not sure why my g++ doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 4):

The information you seek is needed by debuggers and is emitted for them when you compile with `-g`. On ELF/DWARF platforms (such as Linux), you can see what's there by executing:

```
g++ -g -c foo.cc
readelf -w foo.o
```

On other platforms, `objdump -g foo.o` may work.

For ELF/DWARF, [pahole](http://lwn.net/Articles/206805/) looks like a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't have introspection. Once your code is compiled, every piece of information about classes is lost except for what `typeid` and `std::type_info` can give you.

Comment: I don't think he's talking about runtime introspection, but about some compiler option that is able to tell him about the memory layout chosen by the compiler for the objects in his code.