# object byte alignment in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, llvm, memory-alignment, memory-layout

Is there a way to get the compile-time byte alignment of a class instance in Xcode?  In visual studio there is a flag (/d1reportSingleClassLayoutXXX where XXX is the class name) that will dump the class layout to the output window.  Is there a similar flag/function in Xcode?

Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979606/print-layout-of-c-object-with-g-compiler) except for using llvm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to query the layout of a specific object at compile-time, all of the useful information is available via `sizeof(struct X)`, `__alignof(struct X)`, and `offsetof(struct X, member)`.

References:

[__alignof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstddef/offsetof/)

[offsetof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstddef/offsetof/)